# Parse XML from String using XPath in Bada?

Tags: string, file, parsing, xpath, bada

I have read the tutorial on [XML parsing](http://www.badadev.com/working-with-xml-in-bada-part-1-simple-xpath-parsing/) in Bada. But I don't want to use a file. I need to parse my XML from a Osp::Base::String. Any ideas which methods should I use? So far I have replaced

```
xpathCtx = xmlXPathNewContext(doc);
if(xpathCtx == NULL) {
   AppLog("Error: unable to create new XPath context");
   xmlFreeDoc(doc);
   return(E_IO);
}
```

with

```
xpathCtx = (xmlXPathContextPtr) xmlXPathNewCString("<?xml version=\"1.0\" encoding=\"ISO-8859-1\"?><title lang=\"en\">XQuery Kick Start</title><title lang=\"en\">Learning XML</title>");
```

But the emulator simply closes.

Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code is wrong because you cannot cast from xmlXPathObjectPtr to xmlXPathContextPtr: they are different structs.

The code given in the tutorial is right, just use

`xmlDocPtr  xmlReadDoc      (const xmlChar * cur, 
                     const char * URL, 
                     const char * encoding, 
                     int options)`

instead of

`xmlReadFile(..)`

To understand how to use this function have a look at the docs and at the examples on libXML2 website.

Comment: You are quite right my friend. I just wish you had answered my question correctly before I solved the problem myself. The irony here is that I am not currently parsing my XML from a String but from a file, just like in the tutorial. I hope this won't decrease my application performance greatly.